# where and how can I deploy node js application that runs python scripts?

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, hosting, github-pages

I have a project that uses client and server in js. The server runs python's scripts. I tried to deploy the project to github pages and to heruko but I didn't succeed.. it works in the localhost but after I deploy the app it doesn't work.

this is one call for python script for example:

```
const firstPython = (req, res) => {
  try {
    var dataToSend
    const python = spawn('python', ['BOT/sendMessages.py'])
    // collect data from script
    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('Pipe data from python script ...')
      dataToSend = data.toString()
    })
    python.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`)
      // send data to browser
      res.send(dataToSend)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500)
  }
}
```

I will be more specific- the problem is that when I deploy to heroku, this error is shown:

```
     Downloading pytweening-1.0.4.tar.gz (14 kB)
     Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
     Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==303 (from versions: none)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==303
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

we defined to buildpacks in heroku:
heroku/python
heroku/nodejs

Comment: What does *"it doesn't work"* mean? Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a project you are working on and does not have to be live all time I go with [replit.com](https://replit.com/) you app will function but once no requests are coming it'll go into sleep mode, it's a great tool for testing and for portfolio projects.

But, if your project requires to be on all time then I think you have to get a paid server.